# WCF Service An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to Service.svc. 
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol.  This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server  (possibly due to the service shutting down).

```
<bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService"  />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService1" />          
         </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
         <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.104/fin_vyshakh/RemoteService/RemoteService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService"
            contract="RemoteLoanServiceReference.IRemoteService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService" />
         <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.105/fin_vyshakh/RemoteService/RemoteService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService1"
            contract="RemoteDepositServiceReference.IRemoteService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService1" /> 
   </client>
```

In code behind.

```
RemoteDepositServiceReference.RemoteServiceClient client = new RemoteDepositServiceReference.RemoteServiceClient();
string result= client.CallFunction("abc");
client.Close();
```

Comment: My Service.svc in class library project

Comment: Please, add your code

Comment: do you believe that is possible to discover the problem just with the error message? you should share your code and configuration.